# Check integer and fraction length to restrict the input using javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a javascript function that will restrict user input and paste based on set of validations.

User input can have numbers, decimal and comma.

This part is done the next part is to restrict user from entering more than a specified no of integers r fractions.

I tried couple of things but could not get my head around it.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $.fn.checkDecimal = function (integer, fractional) {
return this.each(function () {

    $(this).on("paste", function (event) {

        var val = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'),
                    regex = new RegExp("/^\d{0," + integer + "}(?:[.,]\d{1," + fractional + "})?$/"),
                    test = regex.test(val);

        if (!test) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).on('keydown', function (event) {

        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 8 || event.which == 9 || event.which == 27 || event.which == 13 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
                (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '118' || event.which == '86')) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+c
                (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '99' || event.which == '67')) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.which == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.which >= 35 && event.which <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            //// Ensure that it is a number and stop the keydown

            //Only allow period, comma and numbers
            if (event.which != 8 &&
                    (event.which != 190 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
                    (event.which != 188 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                    (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

                //Only specified numbers after a decimal
            else if (event.which != 8 &&
                        (event.which > 48 || event.which < 57) &&
                        ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                        ($(this).val().indexOf('.') < $(this).val().length - fractional)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
                //Only specified numbers before a decimal
            else if (event.which != 8 &&
                        (event.which > 48 || event.which < 57) &&
                        ($(this).val().length == integer) &&
                         $(this).val().indexOf('.') == -1 &&
                        (event.which != 190 && event.which != 188)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    }).on("keyup", function (event) {

        var val = $(this).val();

        $(this).val(val.replace(',', '.'));

    });
});
}
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#restrictiveDecimals').checkDecimal(4,3);
  });
  
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Only Numbers, Dot & Comma allowed
  <br>
  But need to restrict input length
</label> 
<input type="text" id="restrictiveDecimals">
```

Comment: You should try to simplify your code down to just the part that is not working. People here won't want to look through all of your code to find your problems, and the first step of debugging is isolating where something has gone wrong, and simplifying it down as much as possible shows to the community that you have "done your part". I can tell you at least one of your problems is in the else if after "only two numbers after a decimal" you probably meant to check > 48 and < 57 because you are wanting to restrict the number of digits entered.

Comment: @TJRockefeller you can move you comment to answer as it helped me fix the issue. I have updated the code. I have two more issues, one the above code does not work if i select existing text and press a number key second if I use left arrow key it returns to right. Any idea on this.

Comment: @NikhilGupta I ran your code in OP. It restricted me after 4 integers ! Can you please explain your problem so that I can understand and help ;)

Comment: @TusharGupta, code is supposed to allow decimals in the form of 4,3. So u can enter 4 digits max and after that u can only enter comma r dot and then 3 digits max. Its works fine as per expectation but if I select the text using mouse and press any digit, it is supposed to update the value but it does not and also when I use left arrow key to make a selection it does not. U can try both the cases.

Comment: the issue was with keyup event. I moved the code to blur event.

Comment: @NikhilGupta If you found the comment helpful, you can just upvote the comment. If I posted my comment as an answer now it wouldn't really be answering the question since you have edited the original post. Thanks for letting me know that the comment was helpful, though. I don't have time to look into this more right now, but if you haven't figured it out yet I might take a look at this again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
I have intialised 5 integers and 2 decimals.
If you are entering more than 5 digits without keeping '.' , code will place '.' in 6th place.
run it and see..Cheers :)

```js
$(function() {

    $.fn.checkDecimal = function(integer, fractional) {
        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).on("paste", function(event) {

                var val = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text'),
                    regex = new RegExp("/^\d{0," + integer + "}(?:[.,]\d{1," + fractional + "})?$/"),
                    test = regex.test(val);

                if (!test) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            var count=0;
            var no_of_integers = 5;
            var no_of_fractions = 2;
            var int_count = 0;
            var fraction_count = 0;
            $(this).on('keydown', function(event) {
              console.log(count+"-"+int_count+"-"+fraction_count)
                if (int_count == 0 || fraction_count == 0) {
                    if (event.which == 46) {
                        count--;
                        
                    }
                    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                    if (event.which == 46 || event.which == 8 || event.which == 9 || event.which == 27 || event.which == 13 ||
                        // Allow: Ctrl+V
                        (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '118' || event.which == '86')) ||
                        // Allow: Ctrl+c
                        (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '99' || event.which == '67')) ||
                        // Allow: Ctrl+A
                        (event.which == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                        // Allow: home, end, left, right
                        (event.which >= 35 && event.which <= 39)) {
                        // let it happen, don't do anything

                        return;
                    } else {
                        //// Ensure that it is a number and stop the keydown


                        //Only allow period, comma and numbers
                        if (event.which != 8 &&
                            (event.which != 190 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
                            (event.which != 188 || $(this).val().indexOf(',') != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                            (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }

                        //Only two numbers after a decimal
                        else if (event.which != 8 &&
                            (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
                            ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
                            ($(this).val().indexOf('.') >= 0 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') < $(this).val() - fractional)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        } else if (event.which == 190) {

                            int_count = count;
                            count = 1;
                        }

else if (count == no_of_integers) {
                                int_count = count;
                                count = 1;
                                document.getElementById("restrictiveDecimals").value = document.getElementById("restrictiveDecimals").value + ".";
        count++;
                            }      else {
                            if (int_count == 0 && count <= no_of_integers) {
                                count++;
                               
                            } else if (int_count != 0 && count < no_of_fractions) {
                                count++;
                              
                            } else if (int_count != 0 && count == no_of_fractions) {
                                fraction_count = count;
                                count == 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    else{
    event.preventDefault();
    }
            });

            $(this).on("keyup", function(event) {

                var val = $(this).val();

                $(this).val(val.replace(',', '.'));

            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#restrictiveDecimals').checkDecimal(4, 3);
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Only Numbers, Dot & Comma allowed
  <br>
  But need to restrict input length
</label> 
<input type="text" id="restrictiveDecimals">
```

Comment: Your count variable doesn't take into account the ability to delete characters. Instead of incrementing a count it would probably be better to use something like $(this).val().length